# what's the size of std::tr1::array<int, 16> >

Tags: c++, sizeof

I wonder how to get the size of `std::tr1::array<int, 16> >`?

is it just `16*sizeof(int)`, which is how 16 byte?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `sizeof(std::tr1::array<int, 16> >)`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `std::tr1::array` is guaranteed to be an aggregate type that wraps the underlying raw array, which in fact you can access with the `data()` member function. And the size of a raw array is the number of elements times the size of one element.