# sizeof std::array equal to size of plain old array?

Tags: c++, arrays, containers, language-lawyer

Is it guaranteed that `sizeof (std::array<T, N>) == N * sizeof (T)`?

Please provide support from the C++ Standard.

There's [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11854477/103167) about `std::tr1::array`.

---

To get you started:

`std::array` IS an aggregate.  If `T` is *POD*, so is `std::array<T, N>`.  That makes it also *standard-layout*.

There ought to be some Standard reference connecting that to a prohibition on padding (padding for alignment would be allowed, but array length is a multiple of its alignment already).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103244/is-the-size-of-stdarray-defined-by-standard

Comment: @mclaassen: Indeed... and that didn't come up in a search for `[c++] sizeof std::array`.  So best to make this into a pointer to the other (via duplicate closure).